# How to play video android webview?

Tags: android, video, webview, android-webview, android-fullscreen

Video isn't working and  not fullscreen inside webview:

```
    WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
    web.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    web.loadUrl("url/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled hardware acceleration in you app?
Have you implemented WebChromeClient.onShowCustomView?

There is a section on the pieces needed to enable HTML5 fullscreen video at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html.